# How to copy\archive existing files in MSI

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I have an MSI built by a tool that I can not modify (LabVIEW).  So I would like to use Orca or something similar to change the MSI to effectively archive some of the installed files, before the new files are installed.

Below spells out the scenario (sorry so long), but I have tried the MoveFiles and DuplicateFiles with no luck.

Here is what I am hoping.
I run the MSI version 1.0 and lets say file config.txt is installed into the InstallDir.  That file may or may not be changed by the user as they run our application.

Now when I create a new build so I have installer 1.1  When I run that I want it to move the current (potentially modified) config.txt do a directory InstallDir\Archive and then install the new config.txt.  Bonus would be if I can name the archive file something like Archive\1.0\config.txt or Archive\config.txt_1.0.  Something with the version it is coming from.

I have tried to use Orca to use both the MoveFiles table and the DuplicateFiles table with no real luck.  Move never really worked, and duplicate doesn't move the PC file it moves the new MSI file.

I saw https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/movefile-table-movefiles-action and that seems like what I want but I don't really understand the steps needed or how to do it with Orca.

I am not sure if it matters but the file I am testing with does not appear to have a version in the FileTable.

I have also seen a lot of posts about WiX, but that seems to be used to create an MSI and I need to modify one.

As a last resort I could try to zip the directory before the isntall but that could be huge folders.
Thanks

Comment: You could do this with LabVIEW. See the "Application Directory" and "Build Path" VIs, alongside this snippet to pull the version of the main application VI: https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Get-LabVIEW-Executable-Version-Programmatically/ta-p/3520569

Comment: That is from within LabVIEW once the application is installed.  During the installation I want to archive existing files and move them around.  I guess you are right I could install to an install directory then when the exe runs move whatever needs to move, but that seems like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. If you feel like your needs will go beyond simply mirroring a directory structure/set of files into a directory of a given name, you're probably right. For simply copying a few config files, I don't see an issue with writing the few blocks it would take to accomplish this in LV.